# How to set Email From in Laravel?

Tags: php, email, laravel-5.4, swiftmailer

I have a little issue i need help,
I have to set from email in controller dynamically from database in laravel,but now i passed simple static values from email and name.
I tried using

In my controller,

```
 $response = Mail::send([], [], function($message) use ($template,$from_email)
    {   
        $link = url('');
        $rootpath = url('/public').'/';
        $body = $template->content;

        $message->from("riteshkhatri@gmail.com",'Domus');
        $message->to("ritesh@mailinator.com", "ritesh");
        $message->subject($template->subject);
        $message->setBody($body, 'text/html');
    });
```

and i have commented config/mail.php from varible,

but even thought it taking email id from .env its my smtp username to set my mails from value.

See this it taking name from controller and email from my .env file,

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp 
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com 
MAIL_PORT=465 
MAIL_USERNAME=testing.testuser@gmail.com 
MAIL_PASSWORD=//i removed now
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

[image]

If i use email From value from database retrieved value then how can i set   password there??

Comment: any errors? or just not setting it to from? if you are using gmails smtp service. you wont need to set the FROM, it will strictly use the email for the credentials you used in your .env file.

Comment: No errors it just setting From value from the .env file, even though i provide from my controller.

Comment: even i commented From variable array from mail.php file.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to send emails using an email address with password from database. So check this [link](https://laravel.io/forum/07-22-2014-swiftmailer-with-dynamic-mail-configuration)  it may helps you.

Comment: No brother actually i wanted to set only email from value dynamically from database retrieved, but in env the username and password are as it is it sends mail from that .env provided email and password.